# Autoit_WinAPI_SetParent On child move, child disappears

Tags: autoit

The parent window is created by this code:

```
Opt("WinTitleMatchMode", 3)
Opt("GUIResizeMode", 1)
$GUI2 = GUICreate("Consoles", 1020, 600, 0, 0, BitOR($WS_MINIMIZEBOX, $WS_MAXIMIZEBOX, $WS_SYSMENU, $WS_CAPTION, $WS_CLIPCHILDREN, $WS_POPUP, $WS_POPUPWINDOW, $WS_GROUP, $WS_BORDER, $WS_SIZEBOX, $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS))
$hwnd00 = WinGetHandle("Consoles")
DisableButton($GUI2, $SC_CLOSE)
```

The child window(s) is created by this code:

```
Func StartServer($Type, $loc, $ID, $chosen, $Handle, $Name)
    $ID = Run("java " & $chosen & " -Xms512M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar " & '"' & $loc & "\" & $Type & '"', $loc, 5)
    Sleep(300)
    If Not ProcessWait($ID, 5) = 0 Then
        WinSetTitle("C:\Windows\system32\java.exe", "", $Name)
        WinSetTitle("C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\java.exe", "", $Name)
        $Handle = WinGetHandle($Name)
        Sleep(100)
        _WinAPI_SetWindowLong($Handle, $GWL_EXSTYLE, $WS_EX_MDICHILD)
        _WinAPI_SetParent($Handle, $GUI2)
        Sleep(100)
    Else
        MsgBox(-1, "ERROR", "Either the server file was not found or the server crashed because of and internal or a java error. Please check if the jar excists and look after java errors. The program will now exit.")
        ControlSend("Bungee", "", $hwnd0, 'end' & '{ENTER}')
        ControlSend("Server1", "", $hwnd1, "stop" & '{ENTER}')
        ControlSend("Server2", "", $hwnd2, "stop" & '{ENTER}')
        ControlSend("Server3", "", $hwnd3, "stop" & '{ENTER}')
        ControlSend("Server4", "", $hwnd4, "stop" & '{ENTER}')
        ControlSend("Server5", "", $hwnd5, "stop" & '{ENTER}')
        Exit
    EndIf
    Sleep(500)
EndFunc   ;==>StartServer
```

The child window(s) can be moved freely around. If it gets close to the border of the parent GUI, it starts glitching out or it completely disappears.
How can I define the border and prevent child windows to go outside?

Answer (score 0):

As described in another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270920/i-am-using-clipcursor-to-lock-a-mouse-in-a-window-how-do-i-detect-the-height-of/8791888#8791888) at stackOverflow, you can use `_MouseTrap` to prevent this from happening.

Comment: People should be able to change windows at will. It's only when touching the child windows there is any problem. Also, it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: My point was, that while moving the child windows you could trap the mouse in the area that it doesn't occur to get close the the border of the parent GUI. Sorry for being so general in my answer, I didn't have the time to provide some example code.

Comment: The problem isn't when the mouse gets close to the border, but when the border of the child window gets close to the parent window.

Comment: Sorry, I already did some more math in my head that I assumed here...<br>
You can calculate the difference between the initial drag-click where the child window is going to be moved and its border and then trap the mouse so that the child windows border won't get close to the parent window... Is this an option?

Comment: I have been trying for a while now and I found it pretty hard to calculate. Also, it traps the mouse when another window is activated.

Comment: Since it is a window with unknown size inside another window with unknown size on a monitor with unknown resolution and it is a mouse at an unknown position, I don't think I have the mathematical capability to wrap my head around all those nubmers.